# Upload file to Sharepoint Online (Microsoft 365) using Powershell (Option 1-Using PnP.Powershell)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload a file into a Sharepoint Online (M365) library subfolder, but it keeps giving me errors. I have tried many scripts. This post is about using PnP.Powershell (I have posted questions about other scripts hoping someone can help me with any of them)

This is the code:

```
$url="https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysharepointsite/" 

$userID = "mail@foo.com"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "myPaswword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userID, $securePassword

Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell
Connect-PnPOnline $url -Credentials $credentials

$files = Get-Item -Path "C:\myFolder\myFile.csv" -Force
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Add-PnPFile -Folder "myLibraryname/subfolder"  -Path $file.FullName
    Write-Host $done.Name  "Uploaded into the Site" -BackgroundColor Green
}
```

It gives me this error

*Connect-PnPOnline : AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' named 'PnP Management Shell'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.*

How do I grant this permission in M365? Is it safe to grant it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PnP PowerShell need to be granted some privileges on your tenant.

Maybe you can try

```
Register-PnPManagementShellAccess
```

Ref: [Connecting with PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/connecting.html)

I guess it's safe if you ensure you are on the official build and not a customized (hacked) one.

Basically, it will grant the module the right to perform some task using a delegated authorization. It won't have more privileges than your account.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like simple, but I'm concerned about giving the app so many permissions (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjVzcAhyhl4). I'll check it :)

Comment: It's a good habits to not blindly execute command lines from the web ;). That said, as I said all authorizations granted (as for today) are delegated permissions. This means that you still will have to connect using an account that has rights to perform the operation. The PNP Shell will not gain permission your user doesn't have.