# Upload file to Sharepoint Online (Microsoft 365) using Powershell (Option 2 - Using Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload a file into a Sharepoint Online (M365) library subfolder, but it keeps giving me errors. I have tried many scripts. This post is about using Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell (I have posted questions about other scripts hoping someone can help me with any of them)

This is the code:´

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Write-Host "Adding PSSnapin"
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$url="https://mydomanin.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/" 
Write-Host "Connecting to URL..."
$web=Get-SPWeb -Identity $url

if($web)
{
    try
    {
        $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("myLibrary/subfolder")
        $files = Get-Item -Path "C:\MyFolder\myFile.csv" -Force
        foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            $stream = $file.OpenRead()
            $done= $list.RootFolder.Files.Add($file.Name, $stream, $true)
            Write-Host $done.Name  "Uploaded into the Site" -BackgroundColor Green         
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host $ErrorMessage
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Site Doesn't exist"
}
$list.Update()
```

It fails from the beginning:

*Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5*

I Have tried to use Install-Module:

```
Install-Module "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell"
```

But it fails fo find it:

*PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell'*

I suppose the script will also require for credentials. If you can help me with this, I would be grateful, too

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried downloading the package manually from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/16.0.21213.12000 and dropping it into C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules ? try following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell` is for *server side* scripting only. It depends on a local farm on the same computer.

You should take a look at [PnP PowerShell module](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/) which wraps client side APIs (CSOM).

That said, you have to understand the differences beetween SSOM (server side object model) and CSOM (client side object model). Two points in particular:

- SSOM can do anything on a farm / CSOM only provide a subset of APIs, especially regarding administrative operations
- CSOM is mainly a wrapper of HTTP requests. It works in a fashion where you first declare what you need, and then load it. PnP Powershell wraps a part of this complexity, but you shoud really read some docs about the CSOM behavior.

You should ends with something similar to

```
Import-Module PnP.Powershell

Connect-PnPOnline https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite -Interactive

Add-PnPFile c:\myfolder\myfiles.csv -Folder "YourLibrary"
```

Ref: [Add-PnPFile](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPFile.html)

Comment: Hi! I have tried it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405778/upload-file-to-sharepoint-online-microsoft-365-using-powershell-option-1-usin). In that case I receive a message: "The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' named 'PnP Management Shell'". Could you tell me how to grant those permissions in Microsoft 365? (you can answer me in that other post, if you like :) )

Comment: At the end, I installed 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' (Install-Module), and used an script based on it, as i posted in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408704/upload-file-to-sharepoint-online-microsoft-365-using-powershell-option-4-us). Thank you, anyway, for your response, wich guided me in the right direction (CSOM)